# Python 2.7 : UnicodeDecodeError when I use character point with import socket connect

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, encoding, utf-8

I work with python under windows. I have this error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92" when I excecute this simple code :

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((controlAddr, 9051))
```

controlAddr is "127.0.0.1" and I know that it is the character '.' which cause the problem so I tried different conversion but each time, I have the same error. I tried these different ways:

- `controlAddr = u'127.0.0.1'`
- `controlAddr = unicode('127.0.0.1')`
- `controlAddr.encode('utf-8')`
- `controlAddr = u'127'+unichr(ord('\x2e'))+u'0'+unichr(ord('\x2e'))+'0'+unichr(ord('\x2e'))+u'1'`

I added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the begining of the main file and socket.py file.
... I still have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says *'utf8' codec can't decode byte **0x92**"*. In the Windows codepage 1252, this character maps to U+2019 the right quotation mark `’`.

It is likely that the editor you use for your Python script is configured to replace the single quote ('\x27' or `'`) by the right quotation mark. It may be nicer for text, but is terrible in source code. You must fix it in your editor, or use another editor.

Comment: Indeed, I think Spyder causes encoding problem especially with quotation mark. When I launch the script directly in a consol, the problem disapears.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you have a byte 0x92 in your file somewhere, which is not valid in utf-8, but in other encodings it may be, for example:

```
>>> b'\x92'.decode('windows-1252')
'`'
```

That means that your file encoding is *not* utf-8, but probably windows-1252, and problematic character is the backtick, not the dot, even if that character is found only in a comment.

So either change your file encoding to utf-8 in your editor, or the encoding line to

```
# -*- coding: windows-1252 -*-
```

The error message doesn't mention the file the interpreter choked on, but it may be your "main" file, not `socket.py`.

Also, don't name your file `socket.py`, that will shadow the builtin socket module and lead to further errors.

Setting an encoding line only affects that one file, you need to do this for every file, only setting it in your "main" file would not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! Indeed, this character doesn't exist in utf-8.
However, I didn't send the character "`", corresponding to 0x92 with windows-1252 and to nothing in utf-8. Futhermore this error appears when a character "." is in controlAddr and it is the same hexadecimal code for both encoding, i.e, 0x2e.
The complete error message is given above :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\pythonshell.py", line 566, in write_error
    self.shell.write_error(self.get_stderr())
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\baseshell.py", line 272, in get_stderr
    return self.transcode(qba)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\baseshell.py", line 258, in transcode
    return to_text_string(qba.data(), 'utf8')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\spyderlib\py3compat.py", line 134, in to_text_string
    return unicode(obj, encoding)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 736: invalid start byte`

For this code :

`controlPort = 9051
controlAddr = unicode("127.0.0.1")
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((controlAddr, controlPort))`